# Tab bar & Storyboard : Change the default tab

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

I have a tab bar in my storyboard, and 5 tabs.

I want my app to load on the middle tab but I can't find how to do it and where to do it.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question and accept it (you may have to wait a while before it lets you do that). Well done for figuring it out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer !

In appDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBar.selectedIndex = 2;
return YES;
}
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: what should be the code if i need to do so the same on on a button click when I am in 2nd tab bar and need to go to 3rd tab bar ?